# How do you obtain Variance of the "method of moment estimator" for the beta distribution using delta method?

Tags: statistics, gamma-function, variance, delta-method

I'm trying to solve a question where I have to find $V(\hat{\alpha})$ using the delta-method where $V$ is notation for variance and $\hat{\alpha}$ is the method of moment estimator for a beta distribution. To be more specific, I write down the question below:

> Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from the following distribution,

$$f(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha -1}, 0<x<1\text{ and }\alpha>0.$$

> 1. Let $\hat{\alpha}$ be the method of moment estimator. Obtain the $V(\hat{\alpha})$ using the delta-method.

I know that this function is just Beta distribution where $X\sim\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,1)$. So the method of moment $E(X^k)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +1)\Gamma(\alpha +k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha +k+1)}$, where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is a Gamma function.

But how do I get the variance of the method of moment using delta method? I am not sure how the usage of the delta method will get me the variance. Thank you.

Comment: You're estimating only one parameter, so you need only the first moment, which is $\operatorname E(X) = \dfrac\alpha{\alpha+1}.$

In estimation by the method of moments, one sets the sample moment equal to the population moment and then solves that equation for the parameter to be estimated. Thus:
$$
\frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n} n = \overline X = \frac\alpha{\alpha+1},
$$
and then solving this for $\alpha,$ we get
$$
\alpha = \frac{\overline X}{1 - \overline X}.
$$
That is the estimator of $\alpha$ by the method of moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the delta method only gives you an approximation of the variance, which becomes more accurate as $n$ goes to infinity (because it is based on a Taylor approximation).

The variance I get using the delta method is $\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)^2}{n(\alpha+2)}.$ Here is how.

The method of moment estimator $\alpha$ solves the equation
$$ \frac{\Gamma(\hat\alpha+1)\Gamma(\hat\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\hat\alpha)\Gamma(\hat\alpha+2)} = \frac{\hat\alpha}{\hat\alpha+1} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=: \hat\mu$$
where I am using the fact that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.
By inverting this we obtain $\hat\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\hat\mu} - 1$. Therefore we are interested in $\mathrm{Var}(\frac{1}{1-\hat\mu})$. We can use the following Taylor approximation, valid if $\hat\mu\approx\mu = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$ the true mean (which should hold by LLN):
$$
\frac{1}{1-\hat\mu} \approx \frac{1}{1-\mu} + \frac{1}{(1-\mu)^2}(\hat\mu - \mu).
$$

Therefore,
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\hat\alpha) \approx \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{(1-\mu)^2}(\hat\mu-\mu)\right)
= \frac{1}{(1-\mu)^4}\mathrm{Var}(\hat\mu).
$$

Using the fact that $\mathrm{Var}(\hat \mu)$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ times the variance of a single $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, 1)$ variable, which is $\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+1)^2(\alpha+2)}$, and plugging in $1-\mu = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}$, we obtain the final answer for the delta method approximated variance

$$
\mathrm{Var}(\hat\mu) \approx \frac{\alpha(1+\alpha)^2}{n(\alpha+2)}
$$